# Import Data using HLOOKUP on VBA

Tags: excel, vba, import, vlookup

I am trying to HLookup some data from a sheet to another using VBA, but I got stuck with the code. Basically, in Sheet1 I have the following columns to complete with data from Sheet2:

```
       A    B   C        D      E        F
1   Month   ID  Country  Name   Surname  Email
2   
3
4
```

while in Sheet2, I have the inputs:

```
       A     B     C        D          E         F    G
1   Month    ID    Address  Telephone  Surname   Name Email
2   04-2018  2131  ***      ***        ***       ***  ***
3   04-2018  2133  ***      ***        ***       ***  ***
4   04-2018  2411  ***      ***        ***       ***  ***
```

On excel, I would use the following function, positioned in cell A2:

`=HLOOKUP(A$1,Sheet2!$A$1:$G$5,ROW(), FALSE)`

that works well. However, on VBA the following function reports an error:

```
Function hlookup()

Range("A2").Value = Application.hlookup(Range("A1"), Sheet2.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Select, 2, False)

End Function
```

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Unable to get the Select property of the Range class.

I know the issue is in the range, but I don't find the way to make it work.

I am very new on VBA and I tried to make it simple and clear, so any suggestions on how to improve the code will be well accepted.

Comment: Remove that `.Select`. In any case `Range("a1").End(xlDown)` will return a single cell.

Comment: Don't name your function `hlookup` because this is already a function name used by Excel! Also it should be a procedure `Sub` not a `function` because it doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to lookup each row if you just want to reorder the columns.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyData()
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = wsSrc.Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim DestHeader As Range
    Set DestHeader = wsDest.Range(wsDest.Range("A1"), wsDest.Cells(1, wsDest.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

    Dim SrcHeader As Range
    Set SrcHeader = wsSrc.Range(wsSrc.Range("A1"), wsSrc.Cells(1, wsSrc.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In DestHeader
        Set FoundCell = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set FoundCell = SrcHeader.Find(What:=Cell.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            Cell.Offset(1).Resize(LastRow - 1).Value = FoundCell.Offset(1).Resize(LastRow - 1).Value
        End If

    Next Cell
End Sub
```